# Running Javascript in a Cloned Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the extend form function. I am trying to run another javascript function within a cloned form but it doesn't work.

If that bootstrap js runs, when a user selects a radio, the radio text would change as in data-complete-text attribute.

The script has worked like a charm when it's not placed in the cloned form.

The bootstrap js fyi
$().button(string): http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Here's the extend form HTML with bootstrap js I'm trying to run (marked in the codes below):

```
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label><?php echo __('Gender'); ?></label><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="gender" id="PostGender_" value="">
            <label class="btn btn-default" id="male" data-complete-text="<?php echo __('Male Selected'); ?>">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="PostGender0" value="0" autocomplete="off"/> <?php echo __('Male'); ?>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default" id="female" data-complete-text="<?php echo __('Female Selected'); ?>">               
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="PostGender1" value="1" autocomplete="off"/> <?php echo __('Female'); ?>
            </label>
        </div>  
        <script> <!-- bootstrap js -->
            $('#male1, #female1').click(function () {
                $(this).button('complete') 
            });
            $('#male1').click(function () {
                $('#female1').button('reset') 
            });
            $('#female1').click(function () {
                $('#male1').button('reset')
            }); 
        </script>               
    </div>  
</div>
</span>
<span id="writeroot"></span>        
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />
```

the Javascript:

```
var counter = 1;
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newField = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newField.id = '';
    newField.style.display = 'block';
    var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name]');
        for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
            var theNames = newFields[i].name
            if (theNames)
                newFields[i].name = "data[Student][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
                //console.log(newFields[i].name);
    }
    var newFields2 = newField.querySelectorAll('[id]');
        for (var i=0;i<newFields2.length;i++) {
            var theNames2 = newFields2[i].id;
            if (theNames2)
                newFields2[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
                //console.log(newFields2[i].id);

    }       
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere);
}
```

I have checked from console that the field ids are named 'male1', 'female1', just as I wanted. The bootstrap js should have found the label with the corresponding id.

P.S. The next question would be to make the js parameter to be incremented so it would be like male1, male2, male3 as the form is cloned. But that's out of the scope of this problem.

Comment: I made this fiddle from your code http://jsfiddle.net/v37w9wns/ - However I do not understand what you want to do or what the problem is

Comment: @Ciprian Mocanu Thanks. I am hoping that, when 'male' radio is selected, the text would change to 'male selected', as set in data-complete-text attribute in label. Same thing to another radio.

Comment: Look at this.. The code is a bit messy, but is this kind-of what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/v37w9wns/1/

Comment: @Ciprian Mocanu Thanks so much Ciprian! Almost. Actually the complete-text has some html like this: "Male Selected <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span>". And can I be cheeky to also ask how the radio text can be set back to default if it is no longer selected?

Comment: @Ciprian Mocanu I've changed to html method to allow the html markup. But I am still stuck as to how to change  the radio text only if it's currently selected.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v37w9wns/2/ - But this is a really messy way of doing it. It's just some quick dirty code. What are you trying to achieve? Custom radios? Cause if that's the case, then there are better ways

Comment: Yes customised radios. Upon selection the text will change to append some html markup that will show a icon. If it's not too much a trouble for you.. what are the better ways?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86604/discussion-between-ciprian-mocanu-and-alvin-mok).